# Setting local to parameter allows use as constexpr?

Tags: c++, constexpr

I'm trying to set up a rather complicated static_assertion to give people a clean error when they call my function. While I seem to be able to make it work, I don't understand *why*. I managed to boil it down to a relatively simple case that I don't understand (`std::is_same` is just used because it's simple). The following compiles happily:

```
template<typename T> constexpr bool IsInt(const T& t){
  return std::is_same<decltype(t), const int&>::value;
}
template<typename T> bool CheckIsInt(const T& t){
  auto s = t;
  static_assert(IsInt(s), "T should be int");
  return true;
}
```

On the other hand, if I get rid of the `auto s = t`, and just use `IsInt(t)`, it fails:

```
template<typename T> bool CheckIsInt(const T& t){
  static_assert(IsInt(t), "T should be int");
  return true;
}
```

with the message (clang++-7):

> static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression

What is going on? What's the difference?

Comment: The problem is that `t` is a reference. I'll find a dupe question with an explanation.